# Java SwingWorker: Nothing displays in textarea

Tags: java, jtextarea, swingworker

I am using swingworker for performing long running task.In between that task, i want to display text in TextArea.The problem is that  i want to display text in the textarea created by me using the netbeans GUI builder but it does not display anything.Here is my code of Main

```
     public class SaveTraffic extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {



    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() throws IOException {


        while (f.num() !=2) {

            {

                publish(captor.getPacket().toString());
                writer.writePacket(captor.getPacket());

            }
        }

        return null;
      }//end main function


      @Override
      public void process(List<String> chunks) {
      for (String text : chunks) {

      f.showPackets(text);
      }
     }
      @Override
      public void done() {
      System.out.println("I am DONE");

   }
```

This is my code in GUI,which displays nothing in textarea though it prints the packets continuously in showPacket function

```
     public void showPackets(String Packet)
     {

       jTextArea1.append(Packet);
     }


      private void jButton3MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) { 
      SaveTraffic p = new SaveTraffic();

      p.execute();

      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much issues with your code, but since it's not complete, I can't locate precisely the issue. Have you made sure that your SwingWorker is actually started by calling `execute()`? What so you see in your logs?

Find below a working example. Try to spot the differences with your code. If you are unable to find the error, then try to post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that will allow us to help you.

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class Test {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextArea textArea;

    protected void initUI() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(textArea));
        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        new SaveTraffic().execute();
    }

    protected void showPackets(String text) {
        textArea.append(text);
        textArea.append("\n");
    }

    class SaveTraffic extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

        @Override
        public Void doInBackground() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                publish("Packet-" + i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void process(List<String> chunks) {
            for (String text : chunks) {
                showPackets(text);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void done() {
            System.out.println("I am DONE");

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I have edited my code, i do call execute but still it does not display anything

Comment: @Zara Have you tried putting some logs in your while-loop? What do you see? If this does not help, post a complete compilable code. The code you are showing us does not contain any particular problem.

Comment: my While loop just contains what i have shown in code, it basically get network packets one by one  which i want to display in textarea.Secondly,what do you mean by logs?

Comment: @Zara Yes, but you could maybe try to put some logging inside the loop to see if you are receiving values and that your condition is evaluated to true. It also throws an IOException, are you sure this exception is not thrown? By logs, I mean that you can output debug information to the console or to a file that gives you information about the execution-flow of your code. For example, put a `System.out.println(packet)` in your while-loop.

Comment: I have put System.out.println(packet) in showPacket() and it displays packets

Comment: @Zara ok good. Post your code for you GUI then, there must be something in there. I can only recommend you to post complete/executable code so that we can help you spot your problem quickly.